# If $P(X=Y)\geq 1-\delta$ and $P(Y>\alpha)\geq 1-\delta$, determine a lower bound for $P(X> \alpha)$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

The question that prompts me to publish this post is the following:

> Let $0<\delta<1$. If $P(X=Y)\geq 1-\delta$ and  $P(Y>\alpha)\geq 1-\delta$, determine a lower bound for the probability $P(X> \alpha)$.

**My attempt:** Using the law of total probability I have obtained the following.
\begin{align}
P(X>\alpha) & = P(X>\alpha|X=Y)P(X=Y)+P(X>\alpha|X\neq Y)P(X\neq Y) \\
  & \geq P(X>\alpha|X=Y)P(X=Y) \\
& \geq P(Y>\alpha|X=Y)P(X=Y) \\
& \geq P(Y>\alpha|X=Y)(1-\delta)
\end{align}

It all boils down to being able to lower bound $P(X>\alpha|X=Y)$, but he doesn't see how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing as conditional probability in the first line, consider writing
$$ \begin{align} 
\Pr\{X > \alpha\} 
&= \Pr\{X > \alpha, X = Y\} + \Pr\{X > \alpha, X \neq Y\} \tag{1}\\
&\geq \Pr\{X > \alpha, X = Y\} + 0 \tag{2}\\
&= \Pr\{Y > \alpha, X = Y\} \tag{3}\\
&= \Pr\{Y > \alpha\} + \Pr\{X = Y\} - \Pr\{Y > \alpha \cup X = Y\} \tag{4}\\
&\geq 1 - \delta + 1 - \delta  - \Pr\{Y > \alpha \cup X = Y\} \tag{5}\\
& = 2 - 2\delta - \Pr\{Y > \alpha \cup X = Y\} \tag{6}\\
& \geq 2 - 2\delta - 1 \tag{7}\\
& = 1 - 2\delta  \tag{8}\end{align} $$

where $(1)$ is using the same law of total probability,
$(2)$ using the axiom of probability that probability is non negative,
$(4)$ is the inclusion-exclusion principle, $(5)$ is using the given assumption, $(7)$ is using the basic probability property similar to $(2)$.